# Any Way To Use Xcode For Flutter Instead Of Android Studio Or VSCode

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, ide

I ask this question only out of curiosity and any answers I receive are greatly appreciated.

As you know, Xcode 12 Beta is out, and it is really amazing and I would really love to be able to use it for developing flutter apps using the Dart SDK. I understand that there might not be any direct way to integrate this into the Xcode IDE but I wouldn't mind trying out any kinds of solutions, no matter how hard it may be. Once again, please ignore this if this is a silly question and if it is not possible at all, though I really appreciate any help I receive and I would like to thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: Xcode doesn't support dart.. so answer is no

Comment: Ohh no... ok thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XCode with Flutter is a terrible idea, even if you want to use it just as a text editor, there is no Flutter and Dart extensions like on VSC or AS

Comment: thanks a lot though I would like to see what other people have to say about this

Answer (score 0):

To develop Flutter apps for iOS, you need a Mac with Xcode installed. Install the latest stable version of Xcode ....
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos